# If you cancel a subversion UPDATE, what happens to so-far downloaded files?

Tags: svn, source-control

Say you "Update" a local svn from a remote repo.  For clarity, say the update will have 100 items (new files) totalling 1gb.

Say the net breaks and the Update is stopped half way through. (Or, you deliberately cancel the update).  Say it has downloaded 50 of the new files, .5 gb of files.

In fact, are the 50 files actually placed in your local copy?? They become part of your local version?

- or (2), does it "hold on to" those files locally (to avoid downloading them again) and then use them only when you can get a whole successful update
- or (3), was the partial download a completely waste: it starts over.

Surprisingly I could not find the answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised no expert had more info on this!

One thing we found from testing:

Interestingly it works on a PER FOLDER basis.

Say there are five folders (say A to E), each containing ten files.

Regarding say folder A, if all ten files are downloaded, in fact it DOES then "show" folder A locally.

However, if you then download say only half of the files inside "C" .. in fact if the Update then breaks or is cancelled, you "do not get" those five files; it seems you only get all or nothing on a **folder basis**.

Hope it helps a future googler.